# Multidimensional SplFixedArray

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, laravel

This is the array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 74
            [coupon] => fCHzP
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 74
            [coupon] => WKHaY
        )
)
```

...etc

And this is the code that makes this array each time dynamically (by a given counter) and then save into db table:

```
for($i=0;$i < $this->counter;$i++){

  $query_params[ ] = array('ID' => $this->ID , 'coupon' => make_random());

}
self::insert($query_params);
```

Ι trying tο write a code that making a multi-dimensional array with **SplFixedArray** but i cant!

I already tried this code (**before loop**) but **is not working:**

`$query_params = new SplFixedArray($this->counter);`

Thanks !

Comment: How is it "not working"?  What does it do?  What doesn't it do?  Do you see any errors?  What's the problem?  "Not working" is not a good way to describe your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `$query_params[] = ...;` doesn't work with `SplFixedArray`.  When you do `$query_params[] = ...;`, you are adding an element *after* the last one.

With `SplFixedArray` `count()` always returns the "fixed" size, so when you push, you are trying to add an element *outside* of its range.

Try this:

```
$query_params = new SplFixedArray($this->counter);
for($i=0; $i < $this->counter; $i++){
  $query_params[$query_params->key()] = array('ID' => $this->ID , 'coupon' => make_random());
  $query_params->next();
}
```

Or, better yet:

```
$query_params = new SplFixedArray($this->counter);
for($i=0; $i < $this->counter; $i++){
  $query_params[$i] = array('ID' => $this->ID , 'coupon' => make_random());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are creating the array is good, Laravel will accept it if your database server accept those lines, but looking at your code I see some strange things:

```
self::insert($query_params);
```

Tells me that this is an Eloquent model, or am I wrong?

```
$this->counter
```

This model has a counter on it, so this isn't a clean model...

```
array('ID' => $this->ID , 'coupon' => make_random());
```

You are trying to `self::insert` the ID again and again? Will that work for your table?